# Tab sequence on js

Tags: javascript, tabs

I am working on tabbing through a webpage on js, but at the end of the cycle, it goes to an intermediary nothingness before going back to the first element. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, you haven't given anything that can help anyone answer your question.  If you post a *SHORT* example, maybe 10-15 lines of HTML, someone might be able to work it out.  In addition, JavaScript itself doesn't really have anything to do with tabbing - unless you've written your own tab manager.  Normally, that's the realm of HTML.  So, you'd do well to:  Post a *short* example that demonstrates your issue and update your tags.  Read this: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

**if wanna give tab index on any control for that you need to write for each one**

```html
document.getElementById("link3").tabIndex = 1;
document.getElementById("link3").tabIndex = 2;
```